# Get actionbar previous title

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I find method or library for make non standart actionbar title. 
I use ActionBarSherlock and method

```
setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In standart case all of I seen in google developers page and some apps used current title, but I need show button back and previos window title.

Example, screen "A" is main menu. When I in screen A I see logo or title "A" without backbutton, when I go from screen "A" to screen "B" I need see backbutton and title "back to A". When I go to screen "C" I need see backbutton and title "back to B".

Upd. To activity "B", or "C" or any another activity I can go from any activity or fragment screen view.

I think create global variable for set title and use in next screen, but I have a lot of screen and maybe its already realised in api or a library?

Answer (score 0):

You could send extra information to the activity within the intent.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityy.class);
  intent.putExtra("PreviousTitle", "Your previous title");
  startActivity(intent);
```

And in the next activity with

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("PreviousTitle");
```

You can get the title. With inhertiance you could make this be done automatically :-)

Comment: I have a lot of screen and not all screen have activity. Some activity show different views(screen) with fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can Set like following:

```
/** ActionBar Settings **/
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

// set defaults for logo & home up
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

#### For Title:

```
//Setting of Title in Activity B:
actionBar.setTitle("Back to A");

//Setting of Title in Activity C:
actionBar.setTitle("Back to B");
```

Comment: I have names of previous screen and want use actionBar.setTitle(methodThatDeterminesScreenFromCame());  And in this app I can go to B not only from A, it can be from any screen.